# Solving a one dimensional wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the partial differential equation $$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}=c^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}$$

For the region $0<x<\pi$ where $t>0$. With the boundary conditions $u(0,\, t)=0$ and $u_{x}(\pi,\, t)=0$ and initial conditions $u(x,\, 0)=x$, $u_{t}(x,\, 0)=0$. I have found my solution to be $$u(x,\, t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{2(-1)^{n}}{\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}\cos{\left[c\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)t\right]}\sin{\left[\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x\right]}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: @MRK that was a typo, it should in fact be $u_{x}(\pi, \, t)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have agrees with what I got.

To increase the value of this answer, here's an animation of the solution:

[image]